# How to run a mvvmcross Xamarin.Form app on an emulator

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, mvvmcross

I am trying emulators to run the app TipCalc and I don't get it. I am working with Visual Studio 2017. Which emulator can I use to run an application Xamarin.Forms and it uses mvvmcross?

Comment: If you are using windows 10 you can run the UWP app.   You could also run the android app and run it in the android emulator.

Comment: I have windows 10. Ok, I can test the app in windows 10. But actually I want to build an app for IOS and Android. In Windows 10 the mvvmcross app works. But on my android emulator doesn't. Which android emulator are you using? Are you using visual studio 2017?

Comment: What's you mean "But on my android emulator doesn't"? Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to build an app for iOS and Android.

### For Android:

First, you need [Accelerating Android emulators on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows). Please choose `Hyper-V` or `HAXM` to acclerate your Android emulator.

Then, you could launch Android emulator form VS `Tools` --> `Android` --> `Android Device Manager`.

### For iOS:

You must have a `Mac` to do `Xamarin.iOS` development. The `Mac` is required for building as well as running the `iOS` simulator.

If you already has a Mac, you just need [Pair to Mac for Xamarin.iOS Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) and build your `Xamarin.iOS` project.